Kotlin withTimeout doesn't cancel okhttp call on background thread
I'm trying to implement a timeout for a network request (using okhttpclient) but without setting a connectTimeout() parameter on the OkHttp client.
Here's how I'm doing it:
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
val res = fetcherUseCase
.fetchData()

}

UseCase class:
    override suspend fun fetchData(): SomeResultObject {
        val res = fetcher.fetchData()
        return when (res) {
            is Failure -> Result.Failure(res.error)
            is Loading -> { Result.Loading }
            is Success -> Result.Success(res.result)
        }

    }


And finally here's the fetcher:
    suspend fun fetchData(): Result {
        var url = ""
        try {

            .......

            val call = NetworkProvider.okHttpClient.newCall(request)

            url = call.request().toString()

            val d = runBlocking { async { call.execute() } }
            
            Log.d("---", "Here 1")
            val response = withTimeout(1500L) {
                d.await()
            }

        } catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {
             Log.d("---", "Here 2")
        }
        return Result.Loading
    }


But this doesn't work. I expected it to throw an exception after 1.5 seconds, but the Network request just goes on and Here 2 never prints.
What am I missing here ?!
Thanks in advance

create a job and cancel the job when it fails. You can search the docs for coroutine jobs and cancel jobs. like job.cancel()

youre not canceling anything

I assume withTimeout should cancel automatically and throw an exception. @kpwnApps

I think you should call executeAsync.

Writing your function like this should allow you to get the timeout behaviour you want:
coroutineScope {
    try {
        .......

        val call = NetworkProvider.okHttpClient.newCall(request)

        url = call.request().toString()

        val d = async(Dispatchers.IO) { call.execute() }
        
        Log.d("---", "Here 1")
        val response = withTimeout(1500L) {
            d.await()
        }

    } catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {
         Log.d("---", "Here 2")
    }
}

Note however that it won't actually cancel the request (unless execute is written to support coroutine cancellation), but it ought to stop waiting for the request to finish.

There's no async. It has to be run within runBlocking

"There's no asyn" There is within the coroutineScope {} block that I added.

Aaah missed that. I tried this @Michael, but doesn't work.

I believe this answer is entirely incorrect. It still waits for the request: https://pl.kotl.in/qpbsaVrgr . It would work if we run async using the GlobalScope, but generally speaking, leaving some requests running in the background isn't a very good approach.

OkHttp library supports both synchronous/blocking mode (execute()) and asynchronous mode (enqueue(), executeAsync()). While it is technically possible to make the blocking code cancellable, it is generally not ideal. It is harder to do and potentially worse for the performance. I suggest using asynchronous mode and especially the executeAsync() function which was added specifically for interop with Kotlin coroutines. It even automatically handles cancellations, so the solution is as simple as:
val response = withTimeout(1500L) {
    NetworkProvider.okHttpClient.newCall(request).executeAsync()
}

This solution actually cancels requests if they timed out. It doesn't leave orphaned tasks still running in the background.
